# ActiveSheet.MailEnvelope

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

have been trying to send email with vba , but i ran in to an unusual problem with the mail envelope, and have seen lots of unanswered problems with this delicate object.

I have discovered through debugging that it locks up when trying to send following code, one problem i resolved was that I needed a range to be selected.

BUT now it is locking up cos i am sending a message with the from field empty.

if i add a break point, add the field manually then resume all goes well,

but i cannot find the proper syntax to do this: **`.Item.From = "me@email.com"`**

```
ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True

'    On Error Resume Next

With ActiveSheet.MailEnvelope
    .Item.To = tech
    .Item.Subject = "some words"
    .Introduction = "some more words"
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1:G5").Select

                 //           from line goes here

    .Send

End With

ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = False
On Error GoTo 0
```

Comment: If your using outlook then I don't thing you will need **`Item.From`**

Comment: mailenvelope creates mail fields inside excel,  but this code locks up both outlook and excel where i had to crash process when i hit send, I have confirmed through trial and error that it is due to the "From:" field being empty. again I am open to suggestions cause i could be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

".From" is .SentOnBehalfOfName

```
.SentOnBehalfOfName = "me@email.com"
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862145.aspx

Comment: thanks! works great,  Also i needed to change "send" to  .Items.Send