# Excel macro to populate table in the email body

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am a beginner in coding and trying to create a macro to send emails to the credit analysts in my team. I am using a sample Excel sheet for the data.

How do I add a 4x2 table in the email body for each credit analyst listed in the sample data? Below is a very basic code which I could create after spending hours.

```
Sub Credit_Auto()
    Dim objOutlook As Object
    Dim objMail As Object
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim strbody As String

    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set Ws = ActiveSheet

    Dim rCell As Range
    For Each rCell In Ws.Range("G2", Ws.Range("G1000").End(xlUp))
        Debug.Print rCell.Address
        Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)

        strbody = "Dear " & rCell.Offset(0, -1).Value & "," & "<br>" & "<br>" & _
          "Please allocate the below account to it's appropriate parent account." & "<br>" & "<br>" & _
          "Regards" & "<br>" & "<br>" & _
          "Ankit"

        With objMail
            .To = rCell.Value
            .Subject = "Unalloctaed Credit Profiles"
            .HTMLBody = strbody
            .Send
        End With

    Next rCell

    Set objMail = Nothing
    Set Ws = Nothing
    Set objOutlook = Nothing
End Sub
```

I need the table with just after the second line in `strbody` (the table should contain data from A to D with headers and the corresponding row of the analyst in column F.)

Here is the sample data [Click Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rH3kWgAgIMnS9SkZILUk4aNwz2BGhVVH/view?usp=sharing)

> [image]

And the final email should look like below for the first email and so on..

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOi28.jpg)

> [image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `strbody = "Dear " & cell.Offset(0, -1).Value` should be changed to `strbody = "Dear " & rCell.Offset(0, -1).Value`

Comment: If you need to mail a table, I would try to e-mail directly from Excel. Check [MAIL ENVELOPE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-mailenvelope-property-excel) property. I use it to e-mail different tables i got in Excel with conditional formatting and more stuff. It works perfect to fit my needs.

Comment: Also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31795075/activesheet-mailenvelope

Comment: You're awesome @Xabier. This problem is fixed now. I have edited the code in question too. Thank you very much. :)

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns thanks for your suggestion. but I am looking for an one-click solution by using VB macro. So that one need not work with different tools and procedures.

Comment: If you need one click solution, you will need to work with collections set a filter and loop while coping -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the script below.  It will let you choose a range to attach to the body of an Outlook email.

```
Sub Mail_Selection_Range_Outlook_Body()
'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm
'Don't forget to copy the function RangetoHTML in the module.
'Working in Excel 2000-2016
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    Set rng = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    'Only the visible cells in the selection
    Set rng = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    'You can also use a fixed range if you want
    'Set rng = Sheets("YourSheet").Range("D4:D12").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected" & _
               vbNewLine & "please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = "ron@debruin.nl"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "This is the Subject line"
        .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
        .Send   'or use .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub


Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
' Changed by Ron de Bruin 28-Oct-2006
' Working in Office 2000-2016
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

Notice this: `Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)`